# How do I get the authorization code for uber oauth

Tags: android, oauth, uber-api

Please help me

https://your-redirect-uri/?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

How do I get the authorization code?

Comment: it is completely not clear what you want.

Comment: clarify your problem in proper way

Comment: I implement uber sdk using oauth sdk.. but i cannot get authorization code after user allow..plzzz hlp

Answer (score 0):

First you should double check if you set the correct redirect url in the dashboard - needs to be the same as one on authorization url. Please follow the steps of the [authentication guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction).

Briefly, you need to:

• Send user to authorize url. It starts by redirecting the user to the authorize endpoint: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI .You can add scopes as well (check 'scope' parameter on authentication guide)

• Receive the redirect with an authorization code. After the user approves the scopes the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri with an auth code that you can post to the /v2/token endpoint to receive an access token.

• Make a POST call to: 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token'
• Store access and refresh token for future use

Comment: You don't need to store auth code - when you get it after authorization is completed - you need to exchange it for access_token by making POST to the /v2/token endpoint. 

So curl for your case will look like: 
curl -F 'clientsecret=EU7rVNp9Jg7eJHQqxqYqgMfcRWUIw8PHNvub5AOk'\
-F 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \ 
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL/'; \
-F 'code=YOUR_AUTH_CODE' \ 
login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token

Comment: plzz send ur code..I need your hlp..in android i implement this

Comment: For more info how to get access_token on Android please check following  [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android#native-login-with-uber-sso)